# day instead of month is saved in db when updating cell in gridview in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

When I try to save the new value in a gridview's cell (it is asp.net - webforms) - the date - it is saved in a wrong way - day is set to month and month is set to day in databae after updating. 
This is a the line of binding the field in gridview:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="AcDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" htmlencode="False" SortExpression="AcDate" />
```

For example there was 05-04-2013 17:00:00 before updating. After updating (without making any changes manually - just entering the edit mode and saving after that) - 04-05-2013 17:00:00
What is the problem?

Comment: Please try May-17th, and see what happens. I suspect you'd get an error in some other place.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tried and get the formatexception: FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: That's good. Now you can go to the place in code where you see this exception, and fix the format string to accept your date.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is being caused by the `DataFormatString` attribute. If I understood your question correctly, the input date is in the format `month-day-year`, and then, after updating, it converts the date to `day-month-year` format correct?

If this is the case, you can fix this issue by changing the value of the `DataFormatString` attribute to the following:

`DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss}"`

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more information on .NET framework `DateTime` format strings and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about the `BoundField.DataFormatString` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine in that case but I need that in browser I have date been formatted like this: 21-03-2013 08:00:00 - so the day is at the first place, after that a month. After changing DataFormatString to {0:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} month is at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding to aspx page first line parameters of culture:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" .......... Culture="ru-RU" UICulture="ru-RU"
```